# Matching Socks Probability Questions

Tags: probability, statistics

So what the question was that a person has 8 pairs of socks(all of them are different), and he just put all of them disorderly in a drawer. So when he goes to work, he just pick any one pair (could be matching or not matching). So what is the probability that at least one time of three days he goes to work has matching pair of socks.

How I approach was that first of all I need to find all the probability that three days he goes to work has no matching socks, lets call it $E_0$. So that $1-P(E_0)$ could be the answer.

So first the probability that he does not get matching pair on the first day would be $\frac{14}{15}$. This was easy.
Which now there would be 2 socks with missing pair (call it $S_m$), and 12 socks still having each own pair ($S_p$) in the drawer. From here there are three possibilities. The second day, he can have $S_m$ and $S_p$ matching, $S_m$ and $S_m$ matching, and $S_p$ and $S_p$ matching. and I calculated it as:

$S_m / S_p$ match = $\frac{2}{14}$$\frac{12}{13}$

$S_m / S_m$ match = $\frac{2}{14}$$\frac{1}{13}$

$S_p / S_p$ match = $\frac{12}{14}$$\frac{11}{13}$

Each respectively would lead to third day having $S(m,p) = \{2,10\} $, $S(m,p) = \{0,12\} $, $S(m,p) = \{4,8\} $. And which the probability for wearing non-matching socks for each situation on the third day will be $\frac{56}{66}$, $\frac{60}{66}$, $\frac{50}{66}$ respectively.

So the Final Calculation will be

$1-P(E_0) = 1 - \frac{14}{15}(\frac{2}{14}\frac{12}{13}\frac{56}{66}+\frac{2}{14}\frac{1}{13}\frac{60}{66}+\frac{12}{14}\frac{11}{13}\frac{50}{66})$

But I am not sure this is right. I remember professor even said we do not need calculator for this question. Please give feedback on my working.

Comment: Is this with or without replacement? (Are the socks washed and replaced each evening?)

Comment: @Henry looks like without replacement, based on the OP's attempt to characterize $S_m$ and $S_p$.  My answer seems to disagree with your work.  If my answer is correct, then I have no explanation of what the professor intended, unless the professor intended that the sampling is done with replacement, rather than without replacement.

Comment: Please post the "do not need calculator" solution for our edification.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that (in effect) you have $8$ pairs of socks, and each pair is a different color.  So, you are in effect asking what the probability is that on all $3$ days, the two socks selected (**without replacement**) are different colors.

I certainly agree with your day-1 assessment of $~\displaystyle \frac{14}{15}.$

On day-2, I am confused by your approach.  That is, assume that the following sock indices describe the pairs: $\{(1,2), (3,4), (5,6), \cdots, (13,14), (15,16)\}.$

On day-2, assuming that day-1 was a non-match, you can assume, without loss of generality that the socks chosen on day-1 were $(14,16).$

So, on day-2, there are $3$ ways of (again) having a non-match:

- Situation-1:
  Both of the socks are in $\{1,2,\cdots,12\}$, but they do not match.  The probability of this happening is 
  $\displaystyle \frac{12}{14} \times \frac{10}{13} = \frac{60}{91}.$ 
  An alternative method of computation of the probability here is:
  $\displaystyle \frac{\binom{12}{2} - 6}{\binom{14}{2}} = \frac{60}{91}$. 
  This situation may be represented, without loss of generality, by a day-2 selection of $(10,12).$ 
  This means that Situation-1 now results in 
  $\{(1,2), (3,4), \cdots, (7,8)\} \cup \{9,11,13,15\}$ 
  remaining for day-3.
- Situation-2:
  One of the socks is in $\{1,2,\cdots,12\}$ and one of the socks is in $\{13,15\}.$  The probability of this happening is 
  $\displaystyle \frac{\binom{12}{1} \times \binom{2}{1}}{\binom{14}{2}} = \frac{24}{91}.$ 
  This situation may be represented, without loss of generality, by a day-2 selection of $(12,15).$ 
  This means that Situation-2 now results in 
  $\{(1,2), (3,4), \cdots, (9,10)\} \cup \{11,13\}$ 
  remaining for day-3.
- Situation-3:
  $(13,15)$ were selected. 
  The probability of this happening is 
  $\displaystyle \frac{\binom{2}{2}}{\binom{14}{2}} = \frac{1}{91}.$ 
  This means that Situation-3 now results in 
  $\{(1,2), (3,4), \cdots, (11,12)\}$ 
  remaining for day-3.

---

For day-3, I will take the $3$ situations that may have resulted after day-2, one at a time:

- Situation-1
  Probability of no match on day-3 is 
  $\displaystyle \frac{\binom{12}{2} - 4}{\binom{12}{2}} = \frac{31}{33}.$
- Situation-2
  Probability of no match on day-3 is 
  $\displaystyle \frac{\binom{12}{2} - 5}{\binom{12}{2}} = \frac{61}{66}.$
- Situation-3
  Probability of no match on day-3 is 
  $\displaystyle \frac{\binom{12}{2} - 6}{\binom{12}{2}} = \frac{10}{11}.$

---

Final computation of **non-match**

$$\frac{14}{15} \times \left\{ ~\left[\frac{60}{91} \times \frac{31}{33}\right] + ~\left[\frac{24}{91} \times \frac{61}{66}\right] + ~\left[\frac{1}{91} \times \frac{10}{11}\right] ~\right\}.$$

Comment: @trueblueanil Thanks for your patience in sticking with it.

Answer (score 0):

**Corrected and simplified answer :28 April '22**

$1-\left(1-\dfrac{\binom81}{\binom{16}2}\right)\left(1- \dfrac{\binom61}{\binom{14}2}\right)\left(1-\dfrac{x}{\binom{12}2}\right)$

The second big $(...)$ evaluates to $= \dfrac{85}{91}$

For  Day $3$, there can be three situations, with $6,5,4$ full pairs available, and we need to find the weighted average of the pairs left intact after $85$ failures.

In the diagrams below, patterns of already taken socks on day $1$ and day $2$ are shown, and $x$ computed

$\quad\quad Type 1\quad\quad\quad\quad Type 2\quad\quad\quad\quad Type 3$

$1\;2\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\quad1\circ\; 2\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\quad1\circ2\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\\2\;1\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\quad2\;1\;\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\quad\circ 1 \circ2\circ\circ\circ\circ$

$x=\dfrac1{85}[\binom22\cdot6 + \binom21\binom{12}1\cdot 5 +\binom61\binom51\cdot 4] = \dfrac{366}{85}, \approx 4.3$

Plugging in $x = \dfrac{366}{85}$ into the formula [yields](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1-%281-1%2F15%29%281-6%2F91%29%281-+%28366%2F85%29%2F66%29)
P(get paired socks on at least one day)$ = \dfrac{397}{2145}$